# Storing of Digital Signature token contents in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, digital-signature

I am working on a web application, where a person with a digital signature could affix one's digital signature in a document uploaded in the web application. I have just started exploring mongo db. Looking for some directions as to whether I would be able to implement storage of digital signatures in the DB and then subsequently retrieve it to affix signatures in an e-application.

Thanks.